# CMErrorDomain when calling CMPedometer methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to access data from `CMPedometer`. I have a class called `StepService` which has the following property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  CMPedometer *pedometer;
```

Which has the following getter

```
-(CMPedometer*) pedometer{
    if(!_pedometer){
        _pedometer = [[CMPedometer alloc] init];
    }
    return _pedometer;
}
```

I'm using the following code to get the steps:

```
-(void) storeData {
    [self.pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]]
                                        toDate:[NSDate date]
                                   withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *err){
                                       if (err) {
                                           NSLog(@"Error getting pedometer data: %@", err);
                                       } else {
                                           ...
                                       }
                                   }];
}
```

When I call the above code like so:

```
StepService *stepService = [[StepService alloc] init];
[stepService storeData];
```

I get the following value for `err`

> Error Domain=CMErrorDomain Code=103 "(null)"

Debugging reveals `pedometer` is not null but `pedometerData` is. What is going on here, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: What's the life of `StepService`? My guess is that `stepService` is too early released. Since `CMPedometer` has to be `strong`, maybe `stepService` too.

Comment: It is in the `viewDidLoad` of a `ViewController`. I'll try making it a property of the `ViewController` and seeing if that fixes things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Larme's advice, I created a property in my `ViewController` and synthesized it, like so:

```
@interface MainViewController(){
@property (strong, nonatomic) StepService *stepService;
@end

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize stepService
```

I was then able to create and call the method containing `queryPedometerDataFromDate` like so:

```
stepService = [[StepService alloc] init];
[stepService storeData];
```